# Sending start address in a loop in increments of 64 as bytes with pyserial

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, pyserial

In the program first I send End address, than I send Erase to delete all previous data. Than send the command to flash new data and than send the start address where to flash data. The start address starts from 0x4000  till end of data in increments of 64. With this above code I want to send 0x4000 as 0x00, 0x40, 0x00 than next time increment it by 64 i.e 0x4040 as 0x00, 0x40, 0x40 and keep on increment it by 64(0x40) until end adress

I am trying to write with Pyserial the start address. Start address is sent as bytes as following

1 chunk 0x00, 0x40, 0x00

2 chunk 0x00, 0x40, 0x40

3 chunck 0x00, 0x40, 0x80

Increment it by 64 and write with ser.write

Its printing wrong data and its increment in 1 byte itself as 40,80 instead of last byte. Any help is appreciated

```
offset = 0
size = 64
Chunk = 0
counter = 0
Total_size = 147456

while(currentoffset < Total_size):
    TempBuff  = []
    No_Of_Bytes = Chunk * 64
    Address = 0x4000 + (Chunk * 64)

    for i in  range(str(hex(Address)).__len__(),2,-2):
        a = Address & 0xFF

        if (str(hex(a)).__len__() < 3):
            b = format(a, '#04x')

        else:
            b = hex(a)

        Address = Address >> 8
        TempBuff.append(b)
        ser.write(b)

        if TempBuff.__len__() < 3:
            ser.write("0x00")
        for indx in range(TempBuff.__len__()-1,-1,-1)  :
            ser.write(TempBuff[indx])

Chunk = Chunk + 1
offset += size
```

Comment: i suspect you want `for address in (start_address,end_address,chunksize)` ... but its hard to tell from this question

Comment: In the program first I send End address, than I send Erase to delete all previous data. Than send the command to flash new data and than send the start address where to flash data. The start address starts from 0x4000  till end of data in increments of 64. With this above code I want to send 0x4000 as 0x00, 0x40, 0x00 than next time increment it by 64 i.e 0x4040 as 0x00, 0x40, 0x40 and keep on increment it by 64(0x40) until end adress

Comment: people just dont understand what you are expecting for output ... forget the serial part and pretend that `print(x)` is the same as `serial.write(x)`  explain what you would expect for the output given a simple input start and end address

Comment: In first loop print  0x00, 0x40, 0x00 i.e print(0x00), print(0x40),print(0x00). during second time in loop print print(0x00), print(0x40), print(0x40). So start number is 0x4000 divided into 3 parts  00, 40, 00 than second time we enter loop we want to print 0x4040 as  print(0x00), print(0x40), print(0x40) increment no by 64(0x40) everyt time we are in loop and print that as 3 parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start_address = 0x4000
end_address = 0x8000
block_size = 64
for addr in range(start_address,end_address,block_size):
    addr_as_hex6 =  "%06x"%addr
    c1,c2,c3 = addr_as_hex6[:2],addr_as_hex6[2:4],addr_as_hex6[4:]
    print("SEND: 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s"%(c1,c2,c3))
```

I guess ...

Comment: Thanks the data works fine just one more question. I am getting data as 00, 40, etc I tried writing ser.write(chr(c1)) to convert it to ascii but it gave me error: TyoeError: An integer is required how can I convert to ASCII other than that of using chr. Thanks

Comment: `ser.write("0x"+c1)` ... c1 is a string already its the 2 digit hex